# Maintaining date information when placing boxplots along the x-axis using plotly in r

Tags: r, date, plotly, boxplot

When placing boxplots along the x-axis using plotly in r, I would like to preserve the date information as the distance between boxes, rather than treating dates as factors and squeezing them uniformly.

I can produce the desired layout if I use the date to specify the color, but I feel there is likely a more 'correct' way to do this.

Thanks all!

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

randomdates <- sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 12)
df          <- data.frame( dates = rep(randomdates, 100), value = sample(1:10, 1200, replace = T)) %>% arrange(dates)

plot_ly(df, y = ~value, color = ~as.factor(dates), type = 'box') # produces the layout that I want
plot_ly(df, y = ~value, x = ~as.factor(dates), type = 'box') # puts even spaces between plots
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Since `dates` are already in date format, does `x=~dates` not do what you want?

Comment: Ugh it was literally that simple, thanks so much!